# Use both positional and unnamed arguments in python dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I am trying to reorganize my code with dataclasses and have stumbled upon a problem. I think I need to create a class that takes 3 positional arguments and then an unknown number of positional arguments. Normally, w/o using dataclasses I'd do something like this:

```
class SomeClass:
  def __init__(self, a, b, c, *args):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c
    self.other = args

sample_object = SomeClass(1,3,5,6,7)
sample_object.other  #yields (6,7)
```

What I can't grasp is how do I put this "other" into dataclass, since when using `field` you provide either default value or default factory otherwise it throws an Exception.

How to write such class using the `dataclass` module?

Comment: I suspect that this is actually not possible (but leave it as a comment, open to be refuted). The dataclass generates the constructor, and not wanting it is like ordering a pizza without bread.

Comment: @Dr.V thanks for the clarification. If so, I guess I'll just stick to basic inits in this case.

Comment: Even if you weren't using a dataclass, I would recommend initializing an instance of `SomeClass` with an explicit tuple instead of arbitrary positional arguments (`SomeClass(1, 2, 3, (6, 7))`). Unlike `**kwargs`, which makes it much easier to implement classes using multiple inheritance, I don't know of a use case that strongly requires (or is significantly simpler with) the ability to accept arbitrary positional arguments, or

Answer (score 2):

You can try to specify `init=False` in your dataclass and the custom constructor:

```py
from typing import List, Any
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(init=False)
class SomeClass:
    a: int
    b: int
    c: int
    other: List[Any]

    def __init__(self, a, b, c, *args):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.other = args

sample_object = SomeClass(1,3,5,6,7)
print(sample_object)
```

Prints:

```
SomeClass(a=1, b=3, c=5, other=(6, 7))
```

Comment: But then of course there isn’t all that much sense in using a dataclass to begin with.

Comment: @deceze Thanks for the suggestion! I hope that there's generally no strict guidelines for using dataclasses over the usual inits, so I guess I'll just stick to it.